# Is this uneven tire wear due to not rotating the tires?

Tags: tires

[image]

I know questions about health are off topic, but how suicidal would it be to keep driving this?

Comment: That is the result of horrible mis-alignment in toe or camber (likely a toe-out alignment issue) Other possibility is bent suspension components from whacking a curb (or large pothole with newer cars)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin so my first job is new tires and axle alignment? If I am unlucky something in the suspension needs to be fixed? I did hit a curb. This is a newer car, but landcruiser, hopefully it can survive a curb.

Comment: Depends on how "bent" bent is. If it is within the range of adjustment for the tie-rods ends and camber adjustment an alignment can take care of it. If it's bent beyond that you will need to replace whatever got bent. Likely an A-arm or spindle. Neither are too costly, the cost will be labor unless you want to do it yourself. You would be surprised. I haven't looked at the lancruiser suspension components, but even some of your 4WD vehicles come with fairly "light" suspension components. Got to keep that CAFE down somehow... (corporate average fuel economy)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not down to "not rotating the tires", that's an alignment/geometry issue, probably the same alignment issue from your [previous question](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/96219/car-pulls-left-rattles-very-hard-steering-wheel-not-straight-when-going-straig). Bin those tires, get some new ones and get a full 4-wheel alignment done.

Comment: Before the OP does any of that, they need to assess (or have assessed) the health of their suspension. Tires on good suspension usually wear straight across. This is primary wear at the inside. If there's a suspension issue and they replace the tires, a 4-wheel alignment isn't going to help much and they'll only be wearing out the new tires in short order. But yes, these tires are shot. I don't even think I'd ride them to the shop to get replaced.

Comment: It's safe to drive on those tires slowly, on a dry day.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 I've seen plenty of examples where wonky alignment alone as caused excessive shoulder wear, but yes it's worth checking the general suspension health as part of the process.

Comment: @GdD - Not no, but heck no. Especially on the steering axle. Just an accident waiting for a place to happen.

Comment: @GdD safe at 1 mph, as far as the tyre depot.

Comment: @motosubatsu I have it in the shop and have them change tires and do axle alignment as they suggested too.